# Docker git clone host key verification failure

Tags: git, docker

I have this in my dockerfile which uses a (.gitignored!) ssh key to authenticate with gitlab in order to pull down a repo.

```
RUN apt-get install -y git
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/
ADD id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN git clone git@gitlab.generalbioinformatics.com:gb-devops/dominion.git
CMD sleep 1000
```

If i run this i get the following error:

Cloning into 'dominion'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

However if i remove the clone step and run the command inside the terminal it works fine, does anyone know whats going wrong here?

Comment: Is the corresponding public key set for the repo?

Comment: `RUN ssh-keyscan gitlab.generalbioinformatics.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts`

Comment: @MarkoE The problem is in Host key, not User key.

Comment: @phd My bad. :)

Comment: No, I think @phd got it right... posted my answer before seeing their comment. If it was a User key the error message would say something related to that effect.

There might be other issues related to the permissions of `/root/.ssh` as well.

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't

`RUN ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts`

be

`RUN ssh-keyscan gitlab.generalbioinformatics.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts`

Remember that `Host key verification` is intended to ensure you are communicating with a "known host". This error is a good example of why it is useful to do so.